# Replace a list property using EnvironmentPostProcessor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a configuration property in my application.yml which is a list. Say it has 5 items. Now using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, I want to replace the property value so that it contains only 3 items. However, I'm finding that it is simply replacing the first 3 items of the list and not replacing the entire list. So my list ends up being a mix of existing and updated values.

application.yml:

```
property:
    - v1
    - v2
    - v3
    - v4
    - v5
```

My post processor (just the main bits):

```
Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();
propertySource.put("property[0]", "n1");
propertySource.put("property[1]", "n2");
propertySource.put("property[2]", "n3");
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("override", propertySource));
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You add a new [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) to the pool with the **[`.addFirst(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html#addFirst(org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource))** method in `ConfigurableEnvironment`.

Your previous `PropertySource` *(source loaded from yml file vs.)* is also available in this pool.

The environment property resolver layer browses all property sources and finds the value and returns it.

Naturally, it can still find the 4th and 5th elements.

###### - The quickest solution would be to use a comma separated list definition:

(I don't know if this suits your use case.)

```yaml
property: v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
```

```java
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();
    propertySource.put("property", "n1,n2,n3");
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
            new MapPropertySource("override", propertySource));
}
```

###### - The longer solution would be to use the [`.replace(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.html#replace(java.lang.String,org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource)) method:

(Removing properties from the property sources that contain your key and then adding a new property source.)

```yaml
property:
    - v1
    - v2
    - v3
    - v4
    - v5
```

```java
@Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        // Clear operation.
        clear(environment);
        // Insert operation.
        Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();
        propertySource.put("property[0]", "n1");
        propertySource.put("property[1]", "n2");
        propertySource.put("property[2]", "n3");
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new MapPropertySource("override", propertySource));
    }
```

```java
private static void clear(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources = environment
            .getPropertySources();
    if (mutablePropertySources != null) {
        List<PropertySource<?>> propertySources = mutablePropertySources
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : propertySources) {
            if (propertySource instanceof OriginTrackedMapPropertySource) {
                clearMapPropertySource(mutablePropertySources, propertySource);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void clearMapPropertySource(
        MutablePropertySources mutablePropertySources,
        PropertySource<?> propertySource) {
    Map<String, Object> oldSource = (Map<String, Object>) 
            propertySource.getSource();
    // Create new source, add old source values
    // ... and remove the ones you don't want.
    Map<String, Object> newSource = new HashMap<>();
    newSource.putAll(oldSource);
    newSource.entrySet().removeIf(o -> o.getKey().startsWith("property"));
    // Replace old source with new source.
    OriginTrackedMapPropertySource originTrackedMapPropertySource =
            new OriginTrackedMapPropertySource(
                    propertySource.getName(),
                    Collections.unmodifiableMap(newSource));
    mutablePropertySources.replace(
            propertySource.getName(),
            originTrackedMapPropertySource);
}
```

The code is included as an example, further improvements or checks may be required. *(For example, removing system properties, etc.)*